# Combining a task (grunt-bump) to start after a prompt via the grunt-prompt task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-prompt

With Grunt I'm running a task which bumps my version number in my package.json file. But I want to prompt the user which versions he/she want's to update. If it's a *normal* update you run a minor increment (x.+1.x), and when its a patch or hotfix it should run a (x.x.+1). For this I have 2 grunt tasks:

```
    /*
     * Bump the version number to a new version
     */

    bump: {
       options: {
         files: ['package.json'],
         updateConfigs: [],
         commit: true,
         commitMessage: 'Release v<%= pkg.version %>',
         commitFiles: ['package.json'],
         createTag: true,
         tagName: 'v<%= pkg.version %>',
         tagMessage: 'Version <%= pkg.version %>',
         push: true,
         pushTo: '<%= aws.gitUrl %>',
         gitDescribeOptions: '--tags --always --abbrev=1 --dirty=-d',
         globalReplace: false,
         prereleaseName: false,
         regExp: false
       }
     },

     /*
      * Prompt to see which bump should happen
      */

     prompt: {
       bumptype: {
         options: {
           questions: [
             {
               config: 'bump.increment',
               type: 'list',
               message: 'Bump version from ' + '<%= pkg.version %> to:',
               choices: [
                  {
                      value: 'patch',
                      name: 'Patch: Backwards-compatible bug fixes.'
                  },
                  {
                      value: 'minor',
                      name: 'Minor: Add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner.'
                  },
                ],
               } 
             ], 
            then: function(results) {
                 console.log(results['bump.increment']); // this outputs 'minor' and 'patch' to the console
             }
           }, // options
         } // bumptype
       }, // prompt
```

And after this I want to run it in a custom task like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', '', function () {
 grunt.task.run('prompt:bumptype');

// Maybe a conditional which calls the results of prompt here?
// grunt.task.run('bump'); // this is the bump call which should be infuenced by either 'patch' or 'minor' 

});
```

But now as I run a `$ grunt test` command, I do get prompted and afterwards it's running the bump minor task no matter which option you choose.

---

The grunt bump option normally takes the following parameters:

```
$ grunt bump:minor
$ grunt bump:patch
```

So should you run a conditional in the prompt options or at the registerTask command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grunt task can be added to the 'then' property of the grunt-prompt:

```
then: function(results) {

    // console.log(results['bump.increment']);

    // run the correct bump version based on answer
    if (results['bump.increment'] === 'patch') {
      grunt.task.run('bump:patch'); 
    } else {
      grunt.task.run('bump:minor');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send parameters to registerTask like this

```
grunt.registerTask('test', function (bumptype) {
    if(bumptype)
      grunt.task.run('bumpup:' + bumptype);
});
```

This way you can do

```
$ grunt test minor
$ grunt test patch
```

Comment: But also the answer from the prompt needs to be called right? The scenario is `$ grunt test`. Then the terminal prompts the user with the question "minor" or "patch". By selecting one or the other you define the task that runs.

Comment: I think calling the parameters like you say is a step in the right direction though

Comment: The advantage with this approach is you don't even need prompt. Since the user is anyways going to type the version in the terminal prompt, they might as well just write it in the command `$ grunt test`

Comment: But the idea with this prompt approach is that you'll only need one command, and then use selection that's user friendly. It won't only be these 2 in the future. Good suggestion though.

Comment: the way to call it should be: grunt test:arg