# use grunt.option in task configuration through grunt.template

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

To put this question simply, I am looking for a way to pass a command line argument, similar to the following, which can be used in my task configuration files.

```
$ grunt mytask --site=abcd
```

To detail my setup, I am using load-grunt-config, so my */Gruntfile.js* file contains just the following...

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
   "use strict";
   require("load-grunt-config")(grunt);
};
```

I then have a */grunt* folder, which has files such as */grunt/compass.js*, */grunt/aliases.js*, */grunt/watch.js*, etc., where each file is the configuration for that task. Here is a sample of my */grunt/watch.js* file:

```
module.exports = {
    compass: {
        files: ['ui/scss/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass:local']
    }
};
```

Now, what I want to do, is something like the following. I would like to use the [grunt.template](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) type format to put in the value I'm passing in from the command line. It doesn't have to be in the grunt.option format, as I could read in the value somewhere else and assign it to a variable/config/etc, but I just cant figure out any way to get that command line option into my config settings.

```
module.exports = {
    compass: {
        files: ['ui/scss/*<%= grunt.option("site") %>*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass:local']
    }
};
```

> My basic problem is that I cannot figure how to get the **<%= grunt.option("site") %>** code, above, to work. (Or something similar, maybe **<%= grunt.config.site %>**)

Within */Gruntfile.js*, I am able to read the option out with the following...

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
   "use strict";
   grunt.log.writeln(grunt.option("site"));
   require("load-grunt-config")(grunt);
};
```

...but from there, I can't figure out how to put that value somewhere that the task config can read it.
Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining a task (grunt-bump) to start after a prompt via the grunt-prompt task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803527/combining-a-task-grunt-bump-to-start-after-a-prompt-via-the-grunt-prompt-task)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, perhaps something in `v.1.0.0`, but I'm currently on the previous stable version `v.0.4.5`.

If you want to access the `grunt.option("whatever")` within your lodash templates `<%= %>` then you need to set it to a property within your `grunt.initConfig({})`.

Let's say you want to have a `--prod` flag when you run `grunt build` to determine if it's prod or not.

You can set:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    ...
    production: grunt.option('prod'),
    ...
```

and then you can use it in your templates as such:

```
templates: {
            ...
            dest: '<%= production ? paths.dist : paths.dev %>/'
        }
```

So when you run `grunt build --prod` the destination folder goes to the right place.